# What 3d engine can be used in 3d editors applications?

Tags: c++, 3d, 3d-engine

but im wander in i need some kind of 3d engine to be used as the core engine for application that in the end will produce me 3d image in good quality
for example application like:
Xara3d , 3D Home Architect , 3d charts .
can it ? ( with combination of Qt )

let me clear my self .. i do not looking for 3d engine this is fine , im going with Irrlicht engine what im asking is how to save the world view as the best quality as possible

Answer (score 2):

You can use [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/) which is directly supported by Qt. If you need a full 3D engine with support for physics, audio etc, try [OGRE](http://www.ogre3d.org/).

Comment: I think that OGRE dose not have direct support for physics and audio, since it's just Object-Oriented Graphics Rendering Engine, other SDK's can be used for that.

Answer (score 2):

With a little work you can embed any OpenGL capable engine (such as OGRE or Irrlicht3d) into a QT frame where the rendering happens. Then you can bind the data structures in the engine (your "world view") to the structures/functions you need to use in the UI.

The other option is to slowly start building your own renderer using OpenGL calls directly.

Depending on how much "integration friendly" the engine API is (or is not), the latter might actually be faster to implement, for simple visualization.